# How to find if a property is attachable or not in wpf ?

Tags: wpf, attached-properties

```
   <Grid Width="100">     

        <Grid.Style>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Ellipse.Height" Value="300"/>
                <Setter Property="Ellipse.Fill" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>                
        </Grid.Style>

        <Ellipse Name="Elp" Width="100" Height="100"></Ellipse>

    </Grid>
```

Above code works as expected except for Ellipse.Fill . My guess is it is not attached property where as Ellipse.Height is . So, how to check if a property is attachable or not ?

Above code doesn't produce any error what so ever.

Comment: I think the problem is you are trying to set `Ellipse.Fill` on `Grid`.

Comment: You can apply attached properties from another classes just fine, that's what they're for! I think the question is how can you find out if a property is an attached property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Fill` property is defined in `Shape` class and not `Grid`. Your code tries to apply `Fill` property in `Grid` which is not valid and thus doesn't work.

Also be aware that `Ellipse.Height` property doesn't belongs to `Ellipse` but `FrameworkElement`. Grid is a framework element and thus it gets applied.

If you think `<Setter Property="Ellipse.Height" Value="300"/>` sets ellipse height to `300`, that's not what happening here. It sets `Grid.Height` to 300.

Comment: You say Fill property doesn't belong to Grid, then we don't get an error ? The code runs just fine.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan There is an error. You just don't know where to look. Please turn on WPF binding errors in `Tools` `Options` `Debugging` `Output Window`. `<Setter />` is a runtime dynamic class, which has no compile time checking. WPF does not stop execution on binding errors.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct that it's not an attached property and so can't be applied to Grid, you can tell if a property is attached in the designer using the tooltip from intellisense

[image]

or if you're trying to find this out from code behind you could do something like

```
   bool IsAttachedProperty(DependencyProperty dependencyProperty)
    {
        DependencyPropertyDescriptor dependencyPropertyDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(dependencyProperty, dependencyProperty.OwnerType);
        if (dependencyPropertyDescriptor != null && dependencyPropertyDescriptor.IsAttached)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

used with the line

```
bool canvasLeft = IsAttachedProperty(Canvas.LeftProperty);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above result can be obtained using

```
    <Grid Width="100">

        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="grdRes">
                <Setter Property="Ellipse.Height" Value="300"/>
                <Setter Property="Ellipse.Fill" Value="Blue"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Background" Value="Green"/>
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Ellipse Name="Elp" Width="100" Height="100">
            <Ellipse.Style>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource grdRes}"></Style>
            </Ellipse.Style>
        </Ellipse>

    </Grid>
```

Also after pressing spacebar attached properties' class names are shown with {} like if you type

```
<Button followed by spacebar
```

it shows {}Grid note curly brace before Grid which shows Grid is exposing attached properties for Button.

And interestingly, number of attached properties changes too depending upon visual tree.

```
<TextBox Width="100" Height="50" FontSize="30" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
```

If TextBox is not present inside a Grid, then Grid.Row is not attached and not shown in intellisense, where as IsSharedSizeScope is shown.